# Spring Cloud Stream - Gracefully Stop Reactive Supplier

Tags: project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring-cloud-stream reactive supplier that streams a finite-length set of data, something like the following.  I'd like to detect that the streaming data has completed, and shut down the spring application.

```
public Supplier<Flux<Map<String, List<Object>>>> streamingDataSource() {

Sinks.Many<Map<String, List<Object>>> sink = Sinks.many()
    .unicast()
    .onBackpressureBuffer();

scheduler.schedule(() -> source.accept(sink));

 return () -> sink.asFlux()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    // TODO - This is terrible - find another way
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    applicationContext.close();
                    System.exit(1);
                }).log();
}
```

When it finishes, that sink calls `tryEmitComplete` which is properly picked up in the `doOnComplete` - however, it does not seem that all of the "outgoing" records have been pushed to the binder - Kinesis in this case.
I can `Thread.sleep()` here for awhile, and hope the outgoing stream finishes in time, but it seems like there must be a way to detect that everything has been processed, or otherwise propagate that complete signal, and shut down spring.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Spring Cloud Stream is not a general purpose messaging framework and was not designed for cases where the applications shuts itself down after "something". And while there are several ways to accomplish what you are looking for all of them would have upside and downside. So consider to just use relevant project (e.g., spring-kafka or spring-amqp) directly where you would have much more flexibility to accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: Finite-length database sources are outside of Spring Cloud Stream's model? I certainly have situations where an `@PollableBean` makes sense to produce deltas... but in this case, I need to sync a specific set of data on-demand, and the service doesn't need to run outside of that..